# From one cpp give list of the head file and hpp file used

Tags: c++, header-files, code-organization

I want to list all header files and `.hpp` files related to this one `.cpp` file. 
The list also needs to include the child header files, `.h` files and `.hpp` files. How can I do this?

Comment: Check your compiler documentation.  Many compilers have command line options to output header file dependencies.

Comment: If you use G++ (the C++ from the GCC — GNU Compiler Collection), then the `-H` option writes (on stderr) the information you seek.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "head file".

But you might find the following useful.  (I have in my makefile.)

> .PHONY: depend .depends: *.hh     $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -M  *.cc  > .depends

It generates lots of information in the file I named ".depends".

HelloWorld.cc is 10 lines.

Typical output of depend contribution:

```
HelloWorld.o: HelloWorld.cc /usr/include/stdc-predef.h \
 /usr/include/c++/7/iostream \
```

...

```
 /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_ios.tcc \
 /usr/include/c++/7/bits/ostream.tcc /usr/include/c++/7/istream \
 /usr/include/c++/7/bits/istream.tcc
```

total lines about 1870.

Using g++ v7.2.0, ubuntu 17.10 (64)

Comment: The ".depends" file has ".h" files, and ".hh" files (my code) and ".hpp" files and maybe some files you think you do not want (so filter them out).